How to display all lines from a form textarea
How to edit the following function to display all lines from a form text area?
Form Textarea:
<textarea rows="20" cols="60" name='cuqts_quotes' id='cuqts_quotes'><?php echo get_option('cuqts_quotes'); ?></textarea>

This is what I've tried but it will not display all lines in a list.
/* Returns texturized all quotes */
function cuqts_get_allqts() {
    $rQuote = explode("\n", get_option('cuqts_quotes'));
    if($rQuote == null || count($rQuote) <= 0) 
        return null;
    foreach($rQuote as $rQts)
        return wptexturize($rQts);
}

/* Display All Quotes Shortcode */
add_shortcode('cuallqts', 'cuqts_get_allqts');


Don't return from a foreach. That will break the loop on the first iteration

Why do you need to explode and loop through it? Why not return it as it is?

When I change return to echo now when I save the page I get the error "Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response."

When I change
foreach($rQuote as $rQts) {
echo wptexturize($rQts); }
to
return wptexturize($rQts);
then no results is displayed.

I have no idea what you are actually trying to do, but the first comment was to not return inside the loop. If $rQuote is an array of things, then presumably you want to loop over each item and call wptexturize on it. Then I guess maybe you concatenate those all together, and finally return that? If these guesses are correct, the code would look something like this. There's several other things I'd change, but like I said, I don't really know what it is ultimately trying to do so I'm leaving those things.

You are doing a return inside the loop. This will stop from looping after the first item.
Add your $rQts into another variable inside the loop and then return after the loop is done.
like this:
/* Returns texturized all quotes */
function cuqts_get_allqts() {
    $quote = '';
    $rQuote = explode("\n", get_option('cuqts_quotes'));
    if($rQuote == null || count($rQuote) <= 0) 
        return null;
    foreach($rQuote as $rQts) {
        $quote .= wptexturize($rQts);
    }

    return $quote;

}

/* Display All Quotes Shortcode */
add_shortcode('cuallqts', 'cuqts_get_allqts');

